# Custom Navigation Drawer doesn't show Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I'm trying to create a favorite list in my app, for this target I used this tutorial:

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/

but to get favorites I used NavigationDrawer instead ActionBar.

The problem is that nothing happens when I choose Favorites or Home in Drawer.

The Logcat shows only one error which not connected with my problem.

Where did I mistake?

Error:

```
06-30 17:41:48.530    6971-6971/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.boom.kayakapp, PID: 6971
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.widget.ImageView.getTag()' on a null object reference
            at com.boom.kayakapp.activities.MainActivity$2.onItemLongClick(MainActivity.java:148)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:3162)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:693)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:693)
            at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:4853)
            at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4822)
            at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8684)
            at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19840)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    --------- beginning of system
06-30 17:41:48.572      933-933/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 933: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-30 17:41:50.823    1232-1274/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '10153f49 com.boom.kayakapp/com.boom.kayakapp.activities.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-30 17:42:02.006    7546-7546/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-30 17:42:02.006    7546-7546/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-30 17:42:02.041    7546-7555/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
06-30 17:42:02.402    7560-7560/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-30 17:42:02.402    7560-7560/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-30 17:42:02.460    7560-7570/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
```

Main Activity:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.boom.kayakapp.R;
import com.boom.kayakapp.adapters.AirlinesAdapter;
import com.boom.kayakapp.adapters.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.boom.kayakapp.controllers.AppController;
import com.boom.kayakapp.fragment.AirlinesFragment;
import com.boom.kayakapp.fragment.FavoriteFragment;
import com.boom.kayakapp.fragment.HomeFragment;
import com.boom.kayakapp.model.Airlines;
import com.boom.kayakapp.model.NavDrawerItem;
import com.boom.kayakapp.util.SharedPreference;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private Fragment contentFragment;
        AirlinesFragment airlinesFragment;
        FavoriteFragment favoriteFragment;

        // JSON Node names
        public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        public static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
        public static final String TAG_SITE = "site";
        public static final String TAG_LOGO = "logoURL";
        public static final String TAG_CODE = "code";

        // Log tag
        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        // Airlines json url
        private static final String url = "https://www.kayak.com/h/mobileapis/directory/airlines";

        public ProgressDialog pDialog;
        public List<Airlines> airlinesList = new ArrayList<Airlines>();
        public ListView listView;
        public AirlinesAdapter adapterAirlines;

        SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    // DrawerLayout

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapterDrawer;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

//            SharedPrefs
            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

//            Json Array
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapterAirlines = new AirlinesAdapter(this, airlinesList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapterAirlines);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

            // Showing progress dialog before making http request
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();

            // Listview OnItemClickListener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String phone = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String site = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.site))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String logoURL = String.valueOf(((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logoURL)));

                    // Starting single contact activity
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SingleContactActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE, phone);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_SITE, site);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_LOGO, logoURL);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });

            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                               int position, long id) {
                    ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);

                    String tag = button.getTag().toString();
                    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
                        sharedPreference.addFavorite(MainActivity.this, airlinesList.get(position));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        button.setTag("red");
                        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                    } else {
                        sharedPreference.removeFavorite(MainActivity.this, airlinesList.get(position));
                        button.setTag("grey");
                        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.remove_favr),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            // changing action bar color
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest airlinesReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Airlines airlines = new Airlines();
                                    airlines.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                    airlines.setLogoURL(obj.getString("logoURL"));
                                    airlines.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                                    airlines.setCode(obj.getInt("code"));
                                    airlines.setSite(obj.getString("site"));

                                    // adding airlines to array
                                    airlinesList.add(airlines);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            // notifying list adapterAirlines about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapterAirlines.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(airlinesReq);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /*
         * This is called when orientation is changed.
         */
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("content")) {
                    String content = savedInstanceState.getString("content");
                    if (content.equals(FavoriteFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FavoriteFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                            setFragmentTitle(R.string.favorites);
                            contentFragment = fragmentManager
                                    .findFragmentByTag(FavoriteFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AirlinesFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                    airlinesFragment = (AirlinesFragment) fragmentManager
                            .findFragmentByTag(AirlinesFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                    contentFragment = airlinesFragment;
                }
            } else {
                airlinesFragment = new AirlinesFragment();
                switchContent(airlinesFragment, AirlinesFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            }

            /*
            From this place DrawerLayout starts
             */
            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            // load slide menu items
            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

            // nav drawer icons from resources
            navMenuIcons = getResources()
                    .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

            // adding nav drawer items to array
            // Home
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            // Favorites
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

            // Recycle the typed array
            navMenuIcons.recycle();

            // setting the nav drawer list adapterDrawer
            adapterDrawer = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterDrawer);

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                    R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                    R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ){
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // on first time display view for first nav item
                displayView(0);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
//        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
//            return true;
//        }
//         Handle action bar actions click
//        switch (item.getItemId()) {
//            case R.id.action_settings:
//                return true;
//            default:
//                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
//        }
//
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                setFragmentTitle(R.string.favorites);
                favoriteFragment = new FavoriteFragment();
                switchContent(favoriteFragment, FavoriteFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
        public void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (contentFragment instanceof FavoriteFragment) {
            outState.putString("content", FavoriteFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        } else {
            outState.putString("content", AirlinesFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()) ;

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
            //Only FavoriteFragment is added to the back stack.
            if (!(fragment instanceof AirlinesFragment)) {
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.commit();
            contentFragment = fragment;
        }
    }

    protected void setFragmentTitle(int resourseId) {
        setTitle(resourseId);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(resourseId);
    }
    /*
     * We call super.onBackPressed(); when the stack entry count is > 0. if it
     * is instanceof ProductListFragment or if the stack entry count is == 0, then
     * we finish the activity.
     * In other words, from AirlinesFragment on back press it quits the app.
     */

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else if (contentFragment instanceof AirlinesFragment
                || fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

FavoriteFragment:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.boom.kayakapp.R;
import com.boom.kayakapp.adapters.AirlinesAdapter;
import com.boom.kayakapp.model.Airlines;
import com.boom.kayakapp.util.SharedPreference;

import java.util.List;

public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "favorite_list";

    ListView favoriteList;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    List<Airlines> favorites;

    Activity activity;
    AirlinesAdapter airlinesAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container,
                false);
        // Get favorite items from SharedPreferences.
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(activity);

        if (favorites == null) {
            showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_items),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_msg));
        } else {

            if (favorites.size() == 0) {
                showAlert(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_items),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_msg));
            }

            favoriteList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
            if (favorites != null) {
                airlinesAdapter = new AirlinesAdapter(activity, favorites);
                favoriteList.setAdapter(airlinesAdapter);

                favoriteList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                            int position, long arg3) {

                    }
                });

                favoriteList
                        .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onItemLongClick(
                                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                                ImageView button = (ImageView) view
                                        .findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);

                                String tag = button.getTag().toString();
                                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
                                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity,
                                            favorites.get(position));
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            activity,
                                            activity.getResources().getString(
                                                    R.string.add_favr),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    button.setTag("red");
                                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                                } else {
                                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity,
                                            favorites.get(position));
                                    button.setTag("grey");
                                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                                    airlinesAdapter.remove(favorites
                                            .get(position));
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            activity,
                                            activity.getResources().getString(
                                                    R.string.remove_favr),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .create();
            alertDialog.setTitle(title);
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

            // setting OK Button
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            // activity.finish();
                            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.favorites);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks pretty self-explaining to me.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object android.widget.ImageView.getTag()' on a null object
>   reference

The button you are trying to find by id after a long click is returning null so you are unable to use the `getTag()` method on that object.

```
ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
```

So you should check if the favorite list is really containing a view (button) with that ID. Try using `getActivity().findViewByID()` instead to test this.

Comment: Edward van Raak, I'm sorry but could you explain more exactly. I can't understand your thought, this button just describes that if item was added to sharedprefs the button must be red if not, so must be grey. How it's depend that my Drawer doesn't show me necessary fragment?